# get value after decimal point in java with precision

Tags: java

Let's say I have:

```
double x = 2.546;
```

I need a `int` that's equal to 5, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 9):

You need to multiply by 10, then cast as an `int`, then apply `%10` operation

Comment: Thank you, figured out this one on my own, but i thought there would be something built in already :)

Comment: lol, nothing built in unfortunately. But it's good that you figured it out yourself! :)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get rid of trailing decimals from a double is to cast it to an int. With some clever casting, we can do this:

```
double x = 2.546;
x-= (int)x;
x *= 10;
int y = (int) x;
```

We remove the 1's position (2) from x by subtracting (int) x which is 2, from x which is 2.546. Then we multiply x by 10 to get 5.46. Then by casting x to an int, we get 5. This would work in many other languages.

Comment: Interesting way of approaching the problem. I would have never thought about it that way!

Answer (score 2):

Can you do this?

```
int intVar = parseInt(x.toString().substring(indexOf('.')+1,1));
```

I haven't actually attempted that, so you may need to tweak.  But that's the idea.

The basic idea is, convert to string, find the decimal point, get the next character after it, and convert it to int.

You may have to flesh it out a bit to handle exceptions.  Like, what if there is no decimal point?